# Favicon is not visible

Tags: favicon

I can not see the favicon in any browser at https://www.example.com

I tried the following implementations:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

and

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

The favicon is in root-folder.

I also checked the Chrome Debugger and it gives me a "200 status ok" for favicon.ico

I tried checking it from multiple places (Work, Home, Smartphone...) - can't see it anywhere.

I also used one of these SEO-Checking sites to check if there is a favicon.
They tell me, that there is one but when they try to show me the favicon they found, it is simply not visible - there is a browser "image not found" symbol instead.

I started implementation more than 24h ago, not sure if it's a a caching problem.

The favicon is in root-folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look well, you are getting a 200 status ok on the favicon, but the type is set to html, and not img.
also if you visit https://www.appfelsine.com/favicon.ico, you get an html page and not the icon image.

Might have something to do with your .htaccess perhaps? Try storing the favicon in your images folder and change the path, see if it works

Comment: Yes it was the .htaccess I think. Did not want to change it so I put the favicon into the images folder. For the future: What did you mean with: "type is set to html and not img". I set the type to image/x-icon didn't I ?

Comment: the browser was handling it as an html document because of your htaccess; moving it into the images folder fixed that

Comment: for more clarification, check this: https://www.appfelsine.com/whatever
this is handled the same way as your favicon was

Comment: Hmmm, thank a lot! Looks like I have to change .htaccess too. appfelsine.com/whatever should return a 404 Page, not an empty page :-)
(U 've got a nice page btw!)

Comment: Yup you should handle that and display a nice error message. and Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your 404 page returns a 200 (instead of a 404), so all those SEO sites see the 200 success and assume the favicon is loaded. Your favicon is not in the correct directory. To confirm this you can open up the page source and click the link to the favicon url and see that it's returning a 404 page. I would recommending putting the favicon in the same folder as other images and linking to it there.

Comment: Thanks, you're right too. Root was not the correct directory in this case. The rules in .htaccess prevent the icon is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that the image is corrupted. My suggestio is to convert it to PNG. Really likely you would have a performance gain that makes this solution worth it.

To convert it:
http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png

Use then:

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="/favicon.png">
```